# Can I join on Contains or like in mySQL?

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have a table called `emails` like this:

```
╔═════════════════════════╦════════════════════════════════════╗
║ subject                 ║ body                               ║
╠═════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════╣
║     Some Subject        ║ Some text .....Client ID: 13456    ║
║     Some Subject        ║ Some text .....Client ID: 13457    ║
║     Some Subject        ║ Some text .....Client ID: 13458    ║
║     Some Subject        ║ Some text .....Client ID: 13459    ║
╚═════════════════════════╩════════════════════════════════════╝
```

and a table named `clients` like this:

```
╔═══════════════╦══════════╗
║ client        ║ clientID ║
╠═══════════════╬══════════╣
║     Company 1 ║ 13456    ║
║     Company 2 ║ 13457    ║
║     Company 3 ║ 13458    ║
║     Company 4 ║ 13459    ║
╚═══════════════╩══════════╝
```

How can I join the two where the `body` column of the first table contains the `clientId` from the second table and get the below result?:

```
╔═════════════════════════╦════════════════════════════════════╦══════════╦═════════╗
║ subject                 ║ body                               ║client    ║clientId ║
╠═════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════╬══════════╬═════════╣
║     Some Subject        ║ Some text .....Client ID: 13456    ║Company 1 ║13456    ║ 
║     Some Subject        ║ Some text .....Client ID: 13457    ║Company 2 ║13457    ║
║     Some Subject        ║ Some text .....Client ID: 13458    ║Company 3 ║13458    ║
║     Some Subject        ║ Some text .....Client ID: 13459    ║Company 4 ║13459    ║
╚═════════════════════════╩════════════════════════════════════╩══════════╩═════════╝
```

I tried this:

```
select * 
from emails e
left join clients c 
on e.body like  c.clientId
where e.subject =  'Some Subject'
```

Unfortunately running the above justs spins for over 5 minutes before I aborted the query which would seem to indicate that it is not correct or is extremely inefficient.

Is it possible to build a query that will do this? possibly by using contains?

---

**All**, thanks for your answers, I'm off till monday and will come back to this when I next go into work.

Comment: `e.body like  '%' + c.clientId`

Comment: You are likely to gain significant performance improvement if you were to store client id as a column in `emails` table

Comment: @PardeepDhingra `on e.body like '%' + c.clientId` gives " Syntax error: '+' (plus operator) is not valid input at this location"

Comment: `e.body like CONCAT('%' , c.clientId)`

Comment: @zedfoxus agreed, unfortunately I need this information from the tables we have which are already populated with over 50,000 rows :(

Comment: The overhead of normalisation may well be trivial compared with the performance benefits

Comment: I agree with Strawberry's comment. A script to add client id column and populating it will be well worth it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you give this a shot?

```
select *
from emails e
left join clients c 
  on e.body regexp concat(': ', c.clientid, '$') = 1
```

Compare the above with:

```
select *
from emails e
left join clients c on e.body like concat('%: ', c.clientid);
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2161/5

```
create table emails (subject varchar(100), body text);
insert into emails values ('test', 'testing: 100'), ('test2', 'testing2: 200');

create table clients (client varchar(100), clientid int);
insert into clients values ('company 1', 100), ('company 2', 200);
```

Results:

```
| subject |          body |    client | clientid |
|---------|---------------|-----------|----------|
|    test |  testing: 100 | company 1 |      100 |
|   test2 | testing2: 200 | company 2 |      200 |
```

Comment: Does this solution help you? You have some good answers for your question. If you are satisfied with answers, please feel free to mark one as accepted to give closure to your question, OP.

Comment: Sorry, Im off work for the weekend and do not currently have access to the database to try any of the answers. Thank you for your time and I will definitely come back to this when I return to work and select an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate `'%'` after and before your `clientID`. (If you are sure that `clientID` will be always the last text in the string, you don't need it after).

```
select * 
from emails e
left join clients c 
on e.body like  CONCAT('%', c.clientId, '%')
where e.subject =  'Some Subject'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new Column in the the email that will automatic calculate the clientID from the body field. So it will only do it one time when you set the body.

try this:

```
ALTER TABLE email
  ADD COLUMN clientId INT AS (SUBSTRING_INDEX(body,' ',-1)) PERSISTENT,
  ADD KEY (`clientId`) ;
```

Then you can use the new field, with a index in your SELECT.

```
select * 
  from emails e
  left join clients c 
  on e.clientId like  c.clientId
  where e.subject =  'Some Subject';
```

Please let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

We can get clientid from body using substring_index() function

```
select * from emails e 
left join clients c 
on c.clientid = substring_index(r.body,':', 1) 
where e.subject = 'Some Subject'
```